# A simple(maybe not as it looks) integration

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I am stuck with a simple-looking integral:

$\int_0^\infty dx \sqrt {x^2+M^2} \cdot e^{-x}$

where $M$ is just a real constant.
I thought it could be expressed with the Modified Bessel Function, but it didn't work well.

Comment: For: `M>0` is: $\frac{1}{2} \pi  M (\pmb{H}_1(M)-Y_1(M))$, Mathematica code:`1/2 M \[Pi] (-BesselY[1, M] + StruveH[1, M])`